# Mobile Data is Off but still i am being charged 0.041INR..Crazy issue on MOTO E.I am using Vodafone Karnataka SIM

Tags: motorola

I have very recently purchased Mote E. I have disabled Mobile data and work only with Wifi.

Even after this I see I am being charged with 0 MB data usage.

enter image description here
(Click for full size)

I don't understand what is happening here. It is coming very frequently. I am very sure none of the Apps are using it since I uninstalled almost every app that I installed after this problem has arisen. I have checked data usage logs and it says 0 MB data usage and that none of my app have used any mobile data.

Why is this happening? Probably some check after wifi gets disconnected? I checked with android debugger but there is too many log statement... anything particular I should be looking at?

Any help or suggestion is apprecia

Comment: Guys..I have copied the Descripton here from one of the previous member who had the exact same problem..Since i felt why think and write the same thing when it is already written...

Comment: Well, first of all, I would check if mobile data is turned on/off on your mobile. If it's always turned off, then I suggest to contact their customer service and ask about the 0.041INR charge. Is it really because of mobile data? Is there any error from their side? Btw, I don't see the image. (PS. I would recommend to remove out your telephone no. or delete the comment altogether to prevent undesirable thing.)

Answer (score 1):

- First Check Out `Settings`>`Data Usage`  that if there is any usage of data connection by any built in app (as you mentioned that you have deleted third party apps)
- If there is not any usage there.As @Andrew T mentioned It must be some problem with your network providers side. Contect them to sort out the matter.